# Why is my alias in CMDER behaving differently than when I enter a file path?

Tags: cmd, terminal, cmder

I'm using CMDER and want to make this filepath: D:\Documents\Programming an alias (pg), so that I can just type "cd /d pg" and cd there. When I type this:

> cd /d D:\Documents\Programming

it works just fine, but when I create an alias like this:

> alias pg=D:\Documents\Programming

then enter

> cd /d pg

I get this result:

> The system cannot find the path specified

Why is that? Just a note, I am using CMDER but figured aliasing is the same across Terminal and Windows CMD.

Comment: There cannot be defined an alias for just a folder path string. There can be defined only an alias for an entire command line. Therefore `cd /d pg` results in the approach to change the current directory to the subdirectory `pg` which does not exist as the error message lets you know. Define the alias `pg` with `cd /d D:\Documents\Programming`. Then you should be able to use `pg` to change the current drive and directory to `D:\Documents\Programming`.

Comment: @Mofi I tried that doing this:
alias pg="cd /d D:\Documents\Programming"

And got this result:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Please read the documentation page about [Cmder Aliases](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Cmder-Aliases). `alias pg="cd /d D:\Documents\Programming` is of wrong syntax because of the single `"` which lets `cmd.exe` think it should run the file `"cd /d D:\Documents\Programming"`. Define the alias `pg` with `alias pg=cd /d D:\Documents\Programming`

Comment: Thank you for reporting my last comment, it was a compliment but I see the error of my ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> alias pg="cd /d D:\Documents\Programming"

is of wrong syntax because of the single " which lets cmd.exe think it should run the file "cd /d D:\Documents\Programming". Define the alias pg with

> alias pg=cd /d D:\Documents\Programming

reposted @Mofi's answer here because commments can't be marked as answers. Feel free to post your answer if you want your answer accepted and I'll delete this one!